# How to parse records to html-table in django templates

Tags: django, templates, html-table, crosstab

let's say I have the following data: (by annotate queryset)

```
games = ['A','B','C']
names = ['John','Tom']
records = [
{'name':'John', 'game':'B', 'score':200},
{'name':'John', 'game':'C', 'score':100},
{'name':'Tom', 'game':'A', 'score':300},
{'name':'Tom', 'game':'C', 'score':100}]
```

I want to display on html-table as crosstab:

```
       A    B    C
John       200  100
Tom   300       100
```

So far I can only achieve this by modify the data structure like this:

```
[{'name':'John', 'games':['', 200, 100]},
{'name':'Tom', 'games':[300,'',100]}]
```

Is there any better ways so that I can use the original data without too many modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in Django the philosophy is to reshape your data in the view first, keeping the templates as simple as possible (rather than having complicated reshaping code in the templates)

That said, in your case you can get a long way with this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

pass `['A', 'B', 'C']` into your template context as `columns`

```
{% regroup records by name as grouped_records %}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      {% for column in columns %}
      <th>{{ column }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for group in grouped_records %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ group.grouper }}</td>
      {% for column in columns %}
      <td>
        {% for record in group.list %}
          {% if record.game == column %}{{ record.score }}{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

my final decision is to restruct data

first fill all cells with a default value:

```
records = []
for name in names:
    record = {}
    record['name'] = name
    # add other key if need
    record['data'] = [''] * len(games)
    records.append(record.copy())

for data in datalist:
    name = names.index(data['name'])
    game = games.index(data['game'])
    records[name][game] = data['score']
```

then pass to template:

```
...
{% for record in records %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
    {% for data in record.date %}
    <td>{{ data }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

My restruct code is quite long, before use "index".